# (WP) Footer not showing in new single template and 2nd sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, sidebar

my footer shows in the normal page fine. I created a new post template and have this in the footer:

```
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2'))
    get_footer();
```

Like this my widgets show fine. In my functions file I have this:

```
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'child_register_sidebar' );
    function child_register_sidebar(){ register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Sidebar 2 for single_withnotes',
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</section>',
    'before_title'  => '<span class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</span>',
    ));
    }
```

and my new sidebar look like this:

```
    if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) {
return;
    }
    ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
```

Can anyone suggest why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your footer only shows when the "if sentence" is right. dynamic_sidebar("sidebar-2") only returns true when widget "sidebar-2" exists and it has content.

Make sure you have added content to the sidebar-2 in Appearance> Widgets.

Also you should use "is_active_sidebar" in an "if sentence", because dynamic_sidebar sends content to output buffer.

---

If you have content in "Sidebar 2...", other possibility is that there are an error in some of the widgets linked to that position.

Put at the begining of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And watch if some errors are showned in the page.

Also you can remove all content from Sidebar 2 and tried only with some text.

Comment: thanks - not sure I understand though... I have content in my widget. In the widget admin 'Sidebar 2 for single_withnotes' shows with the widgets I have installed and which outputs the widgets.
Don't understand this: "Also you should use "is_active_sidebar" in an "if sentence", because dynamic_sidebar sends content to output buffer." I already have it in my new sidebar.

Comment: When you have conditional statements like an "if" you don't want put something in there that output content outside like a function with and echo or something like that. It isn't a good practice. Also i updated my anwser to add another possibility.

Comment: `<?php if ( !function_exists('is_active_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2'))`
       ` get_footer(); `

There are no errors in the widgets either - I added the code and nothing showed. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: your if statement is: if ( !function_exists('is_active_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2')) or if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2'))??? Because in the first one you are looking for dynamic_sidebar to return false and thats not happen if you have content on it.